# Finding $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'd like to ask something about the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt
$$
I rewrote and took another variable. 
$$
-i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{is}-e^{-is}+8i}{e^{is}+e^{-is} + \frac{10}3} dt
\quad = \quad 
-i\int_{C(0,1)^+}\frac{z-\frac{1}{z}+8i}{z+ \frac1z+ \frac{10}3} \cdot \frac{-i}{z}dt
\quad = \quad
- \int_{C(0,1)^+} \frac{z^2-1+8iz}{z(z^2+1+\frac{10}{3} \cdot z)} dz
$$
The only root of $z(z^2+1+\frac{10}{3} \cdot z)$ inside the unit disk is $0$, so I thought that the integral would equal:
$$
Res_{z=i} \ = \ 2 \pi i \cdot \frac{0-1+8i\cdot 0}{0^2+1+\frac{10}{3}\cdot 0} \quad = \quad 2\pi i
$$

I don't understand why $i$ appears in this value. Can you please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: In the denominator should be $z^2+1+\frac{10}{3}z$, it has another root inside the disk.

Comment: I would say that it is necessary to calculate only $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{4}{\cos t + \frac{10}3} dt$, because $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t}{\cos t + \frac{10}3} dt = 0$

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry

Comment: Just for completion: The numerical value is 18.849555921538776... This is roughly $6\cdot \pi$, which might be the analytical solution.

Comment: I'll delete this post because I've made a big mistake, thank you for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

We first separate the integration into 4 intervals:

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (t+(\pi/2)) + 4}{\cos (t+(\pi/2)) + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (t+\pi) + 4}{\cos (t+\pi) + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin (t+(3\pi/2)) + 4}{\cos (t+(3\pi/2)) + \frac{5}3} dt$$

$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos t + 4}{-\sin t + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-\sin t + 4}{-\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{-\cos t + 4}{\sin t + \frac{5}3} dt$$
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{240}{41-9\cos(2t)}2dt=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{240}{41-9\cos s}ds$$

For this kind of problem it is usually convenient to set $\cos s=\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$ where $x=\tan (s/2)$. Then  $ds =\frac{2dx}{1+x^2}$.

The integral then becomes:

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{240}{9+25x^2}dx=6\pi$$

Comment: And you'll also have to show tat the range of integration needs to be broken in parts too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way. Clearly
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t + 4}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt+4\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt
$$
and 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin t}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt=-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} d(\cos t + \frac{5}3)=0.
$$
You only need to calculate
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos t + \frac{5}3} dt $$
and I think you can finish it.